# Bundling and Minification not working in MVC4 with JqueryMobile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-mobile

I am using bundling and minification in MVC4 with Jquery Mobile 1.4 to create Web Application.

In project Login Page which is not derived from Layout Page. contain 4 Bundling there are

```
 @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Custom")
```

Which Works Great but it applicable only to one Login View.

After User Logs in Other Pages derived from Master Layout. So we thought to have all .js and .css in Master Page. With above 4 bundle we added 1 more bundle.

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/Custom")
  **@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AppCustom")**
```

But browser not loading   **@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/AppCustom")** function in this file is not hitting. Please guide Me.

Comment: Can you please provide a description of error which you get on client side?

Comment: @U10: not getting any error. The problem is browser caching bundling only first time. If i declared any bundle later it is not caching new one.

Comment: But there should be 5 different bundles in your case. and in html you are getting only 4, right?

Comment: Can you provide code of your Login, Layout and any other page?

Comment: Also provide your BundleConfig code.